# Lazy loading templates angularjs using requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

The usual way to load a template using requirejs works great:

```
require 'templates/dashboard', (template) ->
    ...do stuff with template...
```

I want to be able to load the template on demand in the routeProvider:

```
$routeProvider.when '/admin',
   template: require('templates/dashboard')
   controller: 'AdminController'
```

How do i get routeProvider to wait for require to return?

Comment: why would you do this. the routeprovider downloads the template async itself if you just do templateURL:'whatever.html'

Comment: Thanks, that gave me the hint for the correct way forward. What i had on the server were AMD scripts with the embedded HTML, which is the regular way to use html with require.js. Your hint that templateUrl is already async just had me change the templates from AMD scripts to regular html templates on the server and voila the browser lazy loaded them on request. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad it includes some examples to work with requirejs and ui-router.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for this, yes i came across this, but i have been a long time user of require.js and ocLazyLoad seemed suboptimal compared to the power require.js provides. Though i agree it would have solved this problem.